# Inquiry about writing a Char via ByteBuffer

Tags: java, io, nio, bytebuffer

I am wondering why with the following code:

```
SeekableByteChannel seeka = Files.newByteChannel(path,StandardOpenOption.CREATE,StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
    ByteBuffer src = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
    src.putChar('a');
    src.flip();
    seeka.write(src);
```

I get written in the file (path) the following result: **\00a**.
I had expected it would have been different, like only the char 'a'.
If I use a CharBuffer than I cannot pass it to the `seeka.write()` method.
I am making some experiments with these classes, I am aware that there are other ways to write a char or anything else in a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The `putChar()` method in the `ByteBuffer` class writes the Unicode for a char into the buffer. This is 16 bits or more. So when you call `putChar('a')`, you are putting the Unicode for 'a' into the buffer rather than the char 'a'. When you write this buffer with the `SeekableByteChannel`, you are writing this unicode to file, because this is what's in your buffer.

Luckily, it is a fairly simple task to convert this Unicode back into chars when reading the files. You can use the `read()` method in `SeekableByteChannel` to read the bytes into a `ByteBuffer`, and then call the `asCharBuffer()` method in `ByteBuffer` to treat the `ByteBuffer` as a `CharBuffer`, which will allow you to read in chars. Alternatively, you could repeatedly call the `getChar()` method in `ByteBuffer` to read in a single `char`. If you're looking to simply write chars to file, however, you will have to resort to a different method.

Comment: I see, and with FileOutputStream  it write down directly the mere sheer simple byte right? without bytecodes..  that's why it works reading and writing chars from a file with FileOutputStream.. Am I right? PS I am aware that there are FileReader and FileWriter, is just to know how FileInputStream works. Thanks in advance

Comment: However in the API they don't mention about the bytecode:              
Writes two bytes containing the given char value, in the current byte order, into this buffer at the current position, and then increments the position by two.

Comment: @Rollerball Yes he does, and he should edit his answer accordingly if he doesn't want to attract downvotes.